# How can I see the file and package browser in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I just started using Eclipse but already I have a small problem. At first within Eclipse I saw a browser that showed me packages, folders and files on the left. Now it's no longer there. I have gone through I think ever menu item but I still cannot find a way to get this into view.

Can some experienced Eclipse (latest download) user point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: Window -> Show View... -> Package Explorer (default shortcut: Alt+Shift+Q, P)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the button in lower left corner of Eclipse window. If your view is not in popup menu, try '*Other*' and choose whatever you like. In your case it's eiser '*Project explorer*' or '*Package explorer*'

Answer (score 0):

Since you are new to eclipse, I suggest to use the default perspective layout. A perspective is a collection of views and their layout. To reset perspective, Use Window -> Reset perspective.